# How to save date in MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a year as 2012, i want to save to database as 01/01/2012, without adding time to it, only date and not in 1/1/2012.

Comment: Depends on the database engine and which kind of date/time fields that it got and which kind of support the ADO.NET driver has.

Comment: How will you distinguish that from 1st Jan 2012?

Comment: If possible, use a native date type of your database, not string.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're trying to save a string to the database, it doesn't matter what format it's in, as long as you capture the significant parts. A date field in the DB will always contain even those "fields" of the date that you aren't using. It's entirely up to you how you format it once you get it out.

Answer (score 2):

You just need

```
date.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")
```